# Is same package name allowed for a new android app in Google Play?

Tags: android

If I un-publish one android application in google play and tried to publish a new application with same Name and same package ( with a different signature ), will that work?

Anybody tried this before or a faced a similar situation?

Comment: As far as I know, this won't work. You will need different package name.

Comment: From my understanding is package name should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

> Is same package name allowed for a new android app in Google Play?

**Answer** *(By Dianne Hackborn)-*

> No, the most obvious and visible of these is the “manifest package
>   name,” the unique name you give to your application in its
>   AndroidManifest.xml. The name uses a Java-language-style naming
>   convention, with Internet domain ownership helping to avoid name
>   collisions.
>
> Once you publish your application under its manifest package name,
>   this is the unique identity of the application forever more. Switching
>   to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that
>   can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.
>
> If the manifest package name has changed, the new application will be
>   installed alongside the old application, so they both co-exist on the
>   user’s device at the same time.

More from: [**things-that-cannot-change**](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html).

Comment: can i use same package name in a newly created project and uploaded my google play developer account  for same application? will this work?

Answer (score 0):

No, u cant use same package name for new application. Package name should be unique.